# in liferay minimize and restore portlet renders the form panel twice

Tags: javascript, extjs, liferay

We have created a Ext.form.panel inside a liferay portlet. it is a simple form having email, password text box and save button. When we minimize and restore the liferay portlet. The Extjs form elements are rendered twice.

Please someone help me on this issue to overcome.

Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="configPanel"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
 Ext.onReady(function() {

 var addUserForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        renderTo: "configPanel",
        bodyStyle: 'padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;',
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            anchor: '100%',
         },
        items: [{
         xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'url',
        alias:'ac-url',
        id:'ac-field-url',
        itemId:'configPortlet_URL',
        fieldLabel: 'URL',
        labelSeparator:'',
        allowBlank: false,
        vtype: 'url',
        emptyText:'[Required e.g. http://google.com]',
            listeners: {
                //specialkey: submitOnEnter
            }
        },{
            xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'password',
        alias:'ac-password',
        id:'ac-field-password',
        fieldLabel: 'Password',
        labelSeparator:'',
        inputType: 'password',
        allowBlank: false,
        enforceMaxLength: true,
        maxLength: 256,
        emptyText: '[Required]',
                listeners: {
                    //specialkey: submitOnEnter
                }
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Random',
                tooltip: 'Generate a random password',
                style: 'margin-left: 4px;',
                flex: 0,
                handler: function() {
                    //this.prev().setValue(password(8, false));
                    //this.prev().focus()
                }
            }],
        buttons: [{
            id: 'saveBtn',
            itemId: 'saveBtn',
            text: 'Submit',
            handler: function() {
                this.up('form').getForm().submit();
            }
        },{
            text: 'Cancel',
            handler: function() {
                this.up('form').getForm().reset();
            }
        }],
        submit: function() {
            var currentForm = this.owner.form;

            if (currentForm.isValid()) {
                // var newSomething = Ext.create('Something', currentForm.getFieldValues());
            }
        }
    });
    addUserForm.show();
 });
 </script>
```

Below is the image of liferay portlet
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if every time you open the portlet, `Ext.onReady` is fired again.

I guess the easiest solution would be to check for existence of the form before you create it anew:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    if(!Ext.getCmp('ac-field-url')) {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            renderTo: "configPanel",
            ...
            id:'ac-field-url',
            ...
    }
});
```